# How to delay the call of a macro in VBA word?

Tags: vba, ms-word, sleep

I am working in VBA in word and I want to call my macro after every 2 secs
Is there any way around?

Comment: If you do that with a `sleep` like command your Word will not respond anymore and do nothing else than running your macro and waiting (in the waiting time you cannot do anything than wait). While there is the [Application.OnTime method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.ontime) to run a macro at a specific time, I cannot recommend to do that every 2 seconds. That will very likely crash your Word somehow or make it un-useable.

Comment: Note that your question is a [X/Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You asked X but your actual problem is Y. Consider editing your original question and add some information what you are actually trying to do and why you want to do that. • There might be other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

When a document opens, or any other event of your choice, execute the following code which starts the routine using the [Application.OnTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.ontime) method:

```
alertTime = Now + TimeValue("00:02:00")
Application.OnTime alertTime, "EventMacro"
```

Then just have a VBA macro sub called `EventMacro` that will repeat it.

```
Public Sub EventMacro()
  
  '... Execute your actions here'
  
  alertTime = Now + TimeValue("00:02:00")
  Application.OnTime alertTime, "EventMacro"
End Sub
```